# How to implement IK Chain on tube armature to control its bending based on user interaction via touch or mouse in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, animation, game-physics

Any alternative solutions to have control over tube/pipe movement during runtime without animation will be appreciated.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Take a look at FABRIK or CCD solver